# How to add rule to User::create (laravel-8)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to add hashed password to a **User::create($validation);**

UserController

```
public function store_user(UserRoleStoreRequest $request){
    $validated = $request->validated();

    $password = Hash::make($validated["password"]);
    $user = User::create($validated);

    $roles = $validated['role_id'];
    $user->roles()->sync($roles);
    return redirect('/user-role');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the User model

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value){
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
}
```

Comment: I just want to know how i put $password between the User::create($validated);

Comment: then do this $array = collect($request->validated())->forget(['password'])->put('password',$password)->all(); User::create($array);